# Prevent CkEditor from encoding attribute values from source view

Tags: ckeditor

I m trying to include a french accent in a custom attribute value in a div tag by typing `&eacute;` in the source view, however, when I go to the editor view and go back to the source view the `&eacute;` is translated into an é. I would like to still be able to type é in the regular editor and see `&eacute;` in the source, but if I modified the source and added `&eacute;` into one of the attributes, I want ckEditor to leave it as it is.

Example:

currenly, I have

`<div section="section">&eacute;couter<div>`

displayed in the source view and **"écouter"** displayed in the regular view. if I go to the source and change section="section" to `section="s&eacute;ction"`, ckEditor switch it to section="séction", which is not what I wanted.

As I m modifying the source directly, I don't want ckeditor to decode, I want to be able to save it as

`<div section="s&eacute;ction">&eacute;couter<div>`

instead of

`<div section="séction">&eacute;couter<div>`

Please advise.

Comment: Maybe try `&amp;eacute`?

Answer (score 1):

if you want you can use:

```js
CKEDITOR.config.entities_processNumerical = 'force'; //Whether to convert all remaining characters not included in the ASCII character table to their relative decimal numeric representation of HTML entity. When set to force, it will convert all entities into this format. For example : & # 27721;& # 35821;."
```

It will convert to: & # 60;div section=& # 34;s& # 233;ction& # 34;& # 62;& # 233;couter& # 60;div& # 62;

full code:
<div section="séction">écouter<div>